# Modal Window drop down value not updated as per modal value

Tags: angularjs

While editing a drop down in modal window, the drop-down lists for field is not getting updated with model values even though values are seemingly set and served.

I am using angular 1.6.4 and ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js

```
 <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control" s ng-model="OWNER_ID">
     <option ng-repeat="owner in owners" value={{owner.OWNER_ID}}>{{owner.OWNER_NAME}}</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Can you even show how are you updating in controller?

Comment: try giving model as object line value.OWNER_ID and get the value as value.OWNER_ID

Comment: you have to share some more code. is there any error in the console?

Comment: No error in console.   I am updating value by                   
 $scope.OWNER_ID = parseInt(record.OWNER_ID);                                                                                                  $scope.updateRecord($scope.modData);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control"  ng-model="solnData.OWNER_ID"
   ng-options="owner.OWNER_ID as owner.OWNER_NAME for owner in owners" ></select>
```

To overcome the above issue i have used **ng-options** in select tag instead of option tag . That resolved my problem and the result would be